# React Native app to load data on startup for offline

Tags: reactjs, react-native, offlineapps

I want to build an app that would load all the data on first startup so app can be used offline. I also want to refresh the data periodically.

Does anyone have any experience designing that kind of application? I thought of using Firebase/AWS appsync but they don't load the data on startup. They cache the data once you load the page.

The data i have is from wordpress custom posts as well as some documents, images etc. How can I create a functionality to load the data on startup and keep it sync with the server.

Any link to example opensource/github/npm project would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use that pattern,
start by loading your content using a hook, display a loading screen. Once content has loaded, just display the app.

Therefore you can rely on some cache, this is working pretty well with apollo client JS or things like https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query

This article can help your for your app start:
https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-handle-and-design-the-startup-of-a-react-application-da779f3727e5